# The Oreo version of my app can't comprise Nougat version?

Tags: android, version

I have some questions about my application.

1) 1 year ago I released the application in Google.
2) I had many tests with my phone (the version is 'Nougat')
3) the application is working well on my phone still, but another phone which is android version 'oreo' is not working well.

So I guess 7.x and 8.x have some differences?

I don't understand why the 'oreo' can't comprise 'nougat' application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android O has made several changes in terms of Services and how they run, implicit intents and many more.

Most of the changes will apply to your own app even if it doesn't target O. Eg... Your services will get killed if your app isn't in foreground or has any visible component.

You will have to change your logic and code in order for your app to work properly. This is for the greater good and you should conform to these new limits ASAP because future versions will most likely be stricter.

Without more details about the exact issue that you're facing, it's impossible to help you here.

For all changes and details consult their official site:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Comment: hm..Thanks! I have to change these... while the test ASAP.

Comment: can I ask you one more thing??
is the pixel pixel things changed..?? because.. when i released the app, view is so nice, but these days The screen does not fit well..

Comment: Maybe the inflation method might have changed. They've not released this information, sorry can't help you here